# Article use with job title (a sentence from a book)

Tags: articles

The first sentence of the preface for a paperback edition of "The Witch" by Ronald Hutton (Yale University Press, ISBN 987-0-300-23867-9) reads:

> Ronald Hutton is professor of history, University of Bristol, and a leading authority on ancient, medieval and modern paganism, <...>

Shouldn't it be either `a professor` or `Professor of History`?

Comment: Yes, if it is a unique job title I would expect to see _Professor_ capitalised.

Comment: ... and if 'a professor of history' I'd expect 'at the Univer...'.

Comment: They could have said "Ronald Hutton is _a_ professor of history (at _the_ University of Bristol). That would say that he was one among the international community of professors of history. But that would have required both the articles I have inserted. As @KateBunting has said, for a unique post capital letters are most appropriate.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume this is an editor's mistake and there is no other plausible explanation. Does anybody care for putting their comment as an answer? @BoldBen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm upgrading a comment to an answer as suggested by the OP. I apologise for the lack of  supporting evidence which, with the reference to KateBuntin's comment, was the reson for my not posting it as an answer initially.

They could have said "Ronald Hutton is a professor of history (at the University of Bristol). That would say that he was one among the international community of professors of history. But that would have required both the articles I have inserted. As @KateBunting has said, for a unique post capital letters are most appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it should be 'a Professor of History' but it would be more appropriate to say " he is a History Professor" you know like we say "English Professor"  than  "professor of English"